# Paging Horizontal or Vertical ScrollView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, uiscrollview

[image: My Aim]

I am trying to achieve a UI in android without using `ViewPager`. Or you can give advice on something else(including `ViewPager`).

I have a form in three sections and I want the user to click on an icon on the header and the `ScrollView` horizontally scroll to that view. The reason why I'm thinking of a `ScrollView` is because, there are three views and each view has lots of forms. Handling those data would be a tough one if I were to use a `ViewPager`, so I'm looking for a way to use a `ScrollView` or any other way. All I'm concerned about is easy movement for my user, and handling data efficiently cause I want the user to be able to go back and forth within different forms. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use `Fragement Activity` instead

Comment: Please be elaborative enough. You can't do anything view without an `Activity` and `ActionBarActivity` and `ApcompactActivity` already have FragmentActivity in them already right. So, please be a lil bit elaborative

Comment: Ok....Create fragment according to your page requirement and call (Transition) them in your Fragment Activity (eg..As we make navigational drawer..)You can easily context to fragment from main activity and perform your task...And one more thing You have to put extra effort to control scroll view scrolling as it provide smooth scrolling not index/position based scrolling...